# Inheriting rt.jar source in GWT module

Tags: java, gwt

I need to include/inherit javax.xml.datatype.XmlGregorianCalendar in my GWT module.

I have a proxy gxt.xml called XmlDatatype.gwt.xml, placed within my src tree
src/java/xml/datatype

with the contents:

```
<module>
    <source path="" />
</module>
```

However, java/xml/datatype with the actual source found in ~/java/jdk6/src.zip, which is associated with the JDK1.6 rt.jar of the library path eclipse.

Is there any way around having to unzip src.zip into my project source folder?

1.
Do I really have to unzip that zip file and place them into a source folder visible to my eclipse project? Doesn't GWT know how to look at my rt.jar associated source src.zip and eat the javax.xml.datatype source of that zip?

2.
What about source code which is spontaneously brought in thro maven? Doesn't GWT compiler know how to look into Maven and pull that source from maven? Do I really have to download the source and stick it into a source folder visible to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. GWT always needs the source because the java code gets compiled into javascript. The automatic "looking for source" that you're asking could possibly be done by the GWT eclipse plugin but really doesn't have anything to do with the GWT compiler.
2. Really the same issue as 1.

I think you'll find what you're trying to do to be difficult or impossible because any dependencies from javax.xml.datatype.XmlGregorianCalendar will also need the source included for GWT to try and compile into javascript. This can be tricky when grabbing "any old java lib" because that lib will need to have all its dependencies source included as well. In addition some of those dependencies may not be compatible with browser javascript, such as IO libs, as an example.

Comment: Additionally, GWT doesnt' know about maven - you could be building with ant, or from the command line - so you need to add the source dependencies where needed, that should be enough to give it source for jars that don't have java files in them (but are still translatable - not a lot really are).